# Create 'ObjectTerritory2Association' programatically

Tags: apex, unit-test, territory-management

I've ran into an issue trying to create a `ObjectTerritory2Association` object in a test class. When referencing this object, my class will not compile. There isn't a problem with the code as I can log into another org with Territory Management enabled and the code compiles and runs just fine.

In the org where the code compiles, my user has a `System Admin` profile. In the other, my user has a "System Admin clone" custom profile. I'm not sure if there is a difference, but my first guess is that this cloned profile is missing a permission required to access this object.

When attempting to query from the Developer Console, or compile my class, the error message I'm met with is `Entity is not org accessible`.

I'm not intimately familiar with Territory Management so I'm not sure if there's a setting/permission I'm missing. Any help/nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Edit: 
Looking at one of the answers to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/create-user-with-territory-for-runas-in-test-method?rq=1) question, an error is being thrown at the `Territory2Type` reference.

Comment: ObjectTerritory2Association  object available only if "Enterprise Territory Management" has been enabled for your Salesforce org. Can you check this setting.

Comment: @Devendra Where would I find this setting?

Comment: Follow below navigation, 1. From Setup, enter Territories in the Quick Find box, then select Settings.
2. Click Enable Enterprise Territory Management.

Comment: @Devendra When I follow those steps I'm met with two options, Manage Territories > Territory Settings || Territory Hierarchy.. Also, the fact that there are 'Multiple Territories/Hierarchy', leads me to believe Enterprise Territory Management is enabled

Comment: Can you include code in the question?

Comment: @Devendra I was actually just able to confirm that Enterprise Territory Management is not enabled.. You can make it an answer and I'll close the loop here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the doc, [ObjectTerritory2Association](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_objectterritory2association.htm) Available only if Enterprise Territory Management has been enabled for your Salesforce org.

Follow below path to enable Enterprise Territory Management-

1. From Setup, enter Territories in the Quick Find box, then select Settings.
2. Click Enable Enterprise Territory Management.

Comment: To turn on Enterprise Territory Management, you must request with salesforce. It changes your forecast capabilities and they want you to put in writing that you agree.