# Are Salesforce Account Territories Available in Test Class without seeAllData = true

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup, territory-management, territory

Are territories visible in test class without SeeAllDate=true ?? I have an account created and then I try to query the territory, but it is coming as blank.

```
List<ObjectTerritory2Association> objObjectTerritory2Association = 
    [Select Territory2ID, ObjectID from ObjectTerritory2Association 
      where ObjectID = :objAccount.Id AND Territory2.Name =:'xyz'];

List<UserTerritory2Association> userTerritory2Association = 
  [Select id From UserTerritory2Association 
      WHERE Territory2Id=: objObjectTerritory2Association[0].Territory2ID];
```

Or do I need to setup Territory data first in test class and then retrieve it?

Thanks

Comment: does [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/create-user-with-territory-for-runas-in-test-method) answer your question?  BTW - it is always best practice to mock this so you have a controlled, isolated testmethod that doesn't depend on org data that could change over time

Comment: So I take it as we cannot access the Territories information directly without seeAllData=true. We need to setup territory model, territory and then assign user to it inside test class. correct?

Comment: I'll repeat what I said - best practice is to mock the territories and associations in the testmethod so you have an isolated environment where tests can run repeatedly over time without being subject to the values in the org